# jQuery .filter() elements that do not have variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I turn this:

```
activeSelector = '.active,.selected,.current';

$menuChildren.filter(activeSelector).find('.each-project-content-container').remove();
```

into a filter that is not `activeSelector`?

Some ideas that didn't work so you get the idea:

```
$menuChildren.filter(!activeSelector).find('.each-project-content-container').remove();
$menuChildren.filter(!=activeSelector).find('.each-project-content-container').remove();
$menuChildren.not(filter(activeSelector)).find('.each-project-content-container').remove();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
$menuChildren.not(activeSelector)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$menuChildren.filter(function(index) {
    return $(this).not(activeSelector).find('.each-project-content-container').remove();
});
```

This will do a check on each element that gets passed through the filter and look for an element that doesn't have the `activeSelector` string. If it finds a matching element, then it'll remove the `.each-project-content-container` child elements.

EDIT:

Actually, you don't even need the `filter()` call here. You can simply select all of the non-active elements, find their children of the specified class, and remove:

```
$menuChildren.not(activeSelector).find('.each-project-content-container').remove();
```

That functions the same as above, and is still a one-liner.